# How to manually make field in HTML? Django

Tags: python, html, django, django-forms

in forms.py

```
class PlaceOrder(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Order
        fields = ["Product_ID","HowMany","DateSubmit",]
```

to call a form i usually use

```
{{ Form }}
```

that will render the form automatically
but is it possible to make it manually?
for example i want the form to be exactly like this

```
<input id="Product_ID" type="hidden" value="{{ Product.PId }}" >
<input id="HowMany" type="text">
<input id="DateSubmit" type="hidden" value="{{ date }}" >
```

i have tried wrapping them in

```
{% for field in form %}
```

but it gave the wrong output

Sorry if this is confusing 
but i don't really know how to explain it,
i am still new to Django

Comment: see [Rendering fields manually](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#rendering-fields-manually)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to access individual fields in the form using something like

```
{{Form.Product_ID}}
```

which will give you the Product_ID field widget.

Now if you want to access the already pre-filled data you should be able to do so with

```
{{Form.Product_ID.label}}
```

or

```
{{Form.Product_ID.value}}
```

Also check:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#looping-over-the-form-s-fields

Comment: Bingo just the answer i was looking for but how do i specify the value for {{Form.Product_ID.value}}? thanks

Comment: @SamirPrice welcome to stackoverflow, if this answer solves your problem then please mark it as the correct answer